# Output is derivative of state variable

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear

Given simple system of ODE.

\begin{cases} \dot{x_1}=-x_1+u \\ \dot{x_2}=-x_2-x_1 \end{cases}

As an output, I want to use $y=\dot{x_1}$.

But when I use the `AsymptoticOutputTracker command`, I get the error:  `AsymptoticOutputTracker::drtrz: The direct transmission matrix {{1/Subscript[\[FormalX], 2][t]},{0},{0}} is not a zero matrix.` (code in Mathematica for example).

```
   asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x1'[t] == -x1[t] + u[t], 
    x2'[t] == -x2[t] - x1[t]}, {{x1[t], 1}, {x2[t], 0}}, {u[
     t]}, {(u[t] - x1[t])}, t] // Simplify

pars1 = {Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[p, 1] -> -1};

fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[asys, {Subscript[r, 1]}, {Subscript[p, 1]}] // Simplify;
```

I got the idea to add a differentiating filter:

\begin{cases} \dot{x_1}=-x_1+u \\ \dot{x_2}=-x_2-x_1 \\ \frac{1}{k}\dot{X}+X=\dot{x_1} \end{cases}

And now $y=X \approx \dot{x_1}$ and $k>>1$.

How to transform state-space and get $y=\dot{x_1}$?

Comment: Have you tried it with `u[t]-x1[t]` as the output?

Comment: @LouisB please see my edit

Comment: @dtn Is this optimization problem? Where is your code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev `asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x1'[t] == -x1[t] + u[t], 
    x2'[t] == -x2[t] - x1[t]}, {{x1[t], 1}, {x2[t], 0}}, {u[
     t]}, {(u[t] - x1[t])}, t] // Simplify`

`pars1 = {Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[p, 1] -> -1};`

`fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[asys, {Subscript[r, 1]}, {Subscript[p, 1]}] // Simplify;`

Comment: @AlexTrounev This is me studying nonlinear control theory, section on asymptotic output tracking.

Comment: @dtn What is `pars1` and how it connects with your system?

Comment: @AlexTrounev `pars1` : $r_1$ value to which the output $y$ of the affine system with the dynamics $p_1$ tends asymptotically. The task is to learn how to use derivative of states variables of the affine system as an output. Well, and control them according to the desired law.